# How to determine whether a window has an embedded title bar?

Tags: xlib, titlebar, window-managers

I'm writing a window manager with xlib. If a window has embedded title bar, then window manager won't add title bar for this window. So I'm wondering how to determine whether a window has an embedded title bar?

I've searched in ICCCM and EWMH, and searched in search engines with xlib+"embedded title bar" as keywords, but couldn't find a useful info.

Comment: A window that doesn't want the WM to add a title bar will tell you so. It is not your job to guess.